# How to fix the return value in this typed racket code?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

```
(: test (All (A) (-> A A (Rec Expr (Listof (U A Expr))) (Rec Expr (Listof (U A Expr))))))
(define (test new old expr)
  (if (null? expr)
      expr
      (if (list? (car expr))
          expr ; <- get error here
          expr)))
```

get error

```
Type Checker: type mismatch
expected: (Rec g161252 (Listof (U A g161252)))
given: (Pairof
      (U (Rec g161259 (Listof (U A g161259))) (Pairof Any (Listof Any)))
      (Listof (U A (Rec g161268 (Listof (U A g161268)))))) in: expr
```

The code return exactly the same `expr` as the input one.

```
(define (test new old expr)
  (if (and (not (null? expr)) (list? (car expr)))
      expr ; <- also get the error
      expr))
```

But

```
(define (test new old expr)
  (if (and (list? (car expr)) (not (null? expr)))
      expr ; <- this works fine
      expr))
```

If the logic is in this order, then it works fine.

So why the type checker get the type mismatch error?

Comment: It may be helpful to provide a bit more context about the function so that others can more easily understand the code.

Comment: It's just a test function. You can try the code in Racket IDE. The only context is `#lang typed/racket`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem** with the original code is that `expr` is "not polymorphic enough". The query `(list? (car expr))` changes the type of `expr` to something incompatible with the polymorphic `A`.

(It seems to me that you're trying to discriminate between an `A` and a nested `Expr`, but typed racket sees `list?` and refines the type of `A`. I think!)

Here's another function that's not polymorphic enough.

```
(: id (All (A) (-> A A)))
(define (id x)
  (if (boolean? x) x x))
```

**Fixes**

1. If you're on an older version of Racket (v6.2) you can sneak around this with an alias, but that's not a nice thing to do.

   ```
   (: id (All (A) (-> A A)))
   (define (id x)
     (define x2 x)
     (if (boolean? x) x2 x)))
   ```
2. You can use `list-ref` instead of `car`, because `list-ref` doesn't allow predicates to affect its argument.

   ```
   ...
   (if (list? (list-ref expr 0))
     expr
     expr)))
   ```
3. Change your types a little, so there's a clear way to tell apart `A` from `Expr`.

   ```
   (: test (All (A) (-> A A (Rec Expr (Listof (U (Boxof A) Expr))) (Rec Expr (Listof (U (Boxof A) Expr))))))
   (define (test new old expr)
    (if (null? expr)
     expr
     (if (not (box? (car expr)))
      expr
      expr)))
   ```
4. Stop using Typed Racket's polymorphism -- it's too clumsy!

**The order issue** is because `and` applies predicates in order, and these predicates destructively change an expression's type. So testing `(not (null? expr))` after you've checked `(list? (car expr))` forgets that you ever did the first check.

Here's more code with the same issue. We ought to know that `expr` is non-null *and* has a list at its head, but Typed Racket's forgotten.

```
(: test2 (-> (Listof (U (List Natural) Boolean)) Boolean))
(define (test2 expr)
  (if (and (list? (car expr)) (not (null? expr)))
    (= 1 (car (car expr)))
    #f))
```

This is probably a bug.